# A very strange query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am new in objective c,well I am trying to develop an application.I have an nsdictionary in which I am storing three dates,yesterdays ,todays and next day.Well I am getting my google weather contents parsed in that nsdictionary.Now here the trouble begins...I have to sort my weather elements out based on the dates....dic is :

```
  got {
ConditionDatenew = "2011-07-20 13:36:01 +0000";
Yesterday = "2011-07-19 13:36:01 +0000";
city = #;
condition = "Partly Cloudy";
country = #;
"day_of_week" = Sat;
high = 93;
icon = "partly_cloudy.gif";
low = 76;
newdate = "2011-07-22 13:12:01 +0000";
state = #;
```

Thats my NSDictionary above ...I have to sort my weather elemets out based on the dates and store them in coredata..which I am able to do it..I am not being able to sort things out a...can anyone help me in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate through the weather object to split the date string into char objects.
2. Then use the NSNumber class to do the work of sorting:

   myNum = [NSNumber numberWithChar: '2'];

   NSLog(@"%c", [myNum charValue]);

Answer (score 0):

You can make the date into an NSDate object and then use the instance method -compare:
You could also use the methods -earlierDate: and -laterDate: to see whether a particular date is earlier or later than another one.

Here is the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).